# WARN [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms

Tags: angularjs, macos, requirejs, karma-jasmine

My project is ionic-angularjs-requirejs

My environment is Mac OS X 10.10.1, node v0.10.30

I'd like to integrate karma test to my project but this is error when I run `grunt test`:

**Result:**

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task

INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.28 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket UhgMIttDejE4Xdm8I7mG with id 52208731
WARN [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.

Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**Here is dependencies in my package.json:**

```
"grunt-bower-requirejs": "^1.1.1",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.2.7",
"grunt-karma": "^0.9.0",
"karma": "^0.12.28",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.2",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
"karma-requirejs": "^0.2.2",
"requirejs": "^2.1.15"
```

**Here is my Gruntfile.js:**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    bower: {
        target: {
            rjsConfig: 'js/main.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        options: {
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
        },
        build: {
            src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
            dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
        },
    },
    karma: {
        unit: {
            options: {
                frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
                browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
                autoWatch: true,
                singleRun: true,
                files: [
                    'lib/js/generated/angular/angular.js',
                    'lib/js/generated/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
                    //'js/**/*.js',
                    //'templates/**/*.html',
                    'tests/*.tests.js'
                ],
                exclude: [
                    'js/main.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-requirejs');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');

// Tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'uglify',
    'bower'
]);
grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'karma'
]);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the grunt-karma plugin has been such that I spend more time debugging the plugin than I do my actual site. My solution is to avoid it entirely and use grunt-exec to run my karma command or just not use grunt and run karma manually in a new tab.

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
var config =
    { 
      exec:   {
        karma : 'karma start {path to your karma.conf.js file}'
        // or 
        // karma : 'karma run {path to your karma.conf.js file}'
      }
    }
```

I know that's probably not the answer you're looking for, but my experience has lead me to the understanding that every step away you get from the original program is just an additional program you have to debug that isn't your own.

THAT being said,
your files don't appear to be being included.

I normally break my karma config file into separate files:

### config/files.js

```
module.exports = [
  'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'public/lib/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js',
  'public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'tests/test-main.js',
  {pattern: 'public/js/**/*.js', included: true},
  {pattern: 'tests/unit/**/*.js', included: true}
];
```

### config/common.conf.js

```
var files = require('./files.js');

module.exports = {

  // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
  basePath: '../',

  frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  files: files,


  // list of files to exclude
  exclude: [
  ],

  // web server port
  port: 9876,


  // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
  colors: true,

  // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
  autoWatch: true,

  coverageReporter: {
    type : 'html',
    dir : './tests/coverage/',
    subdir: function(browser) {
      "use strict";
      // normalization process to keep a consistent browser name accross different
      // OS
      return browser.toLowerCase().split(/[ /-]/)[0];
    }
  },

};
```

### config/karma.conf.js

var commonConfig = require('./common.conf.js');

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  "use strict";
  commonConfig.reporters = ['nyan', 'growl'];
  commonConfig.browsers  = ['PhantomJS'];
  commonConfig.captureTimeout = 60000;
  commonConfig.singleRun = false;
  commonConfig.logLevel  = config.LOG_DEBUG;


  config.set(commonConfig);
};

//    commonConfig.browsers  = ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome']
//    commonConfig.browsers  = ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Firefox'],
```

### config/build.conf.js

```
var commonConfig = require('./common.conf.js');

module.exports = function(config) {
  "use strict";
  commonConfig.reporters = ['progress'];
  commonConfig.browsers  = ['PhantomJS'];
  commonConfig.captureTimeout = 120000;
  commonConfig.singleRun = true;
  commonConfig.logLevel  = config.LOG_DEBUG;
  config.set(commonConfig);
};
```

### config/test.coverage.js

```
var commonConfig = require('./common.conf.js');

module.exports = function(config) {
  "use strict";
  commonConfig.reporters = ['progress','coverage'];
  commonConfig.browsers  = ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Firefox'];
  commonConfig.captureTimeout = 120000;
  commonConfig.singleRun = true;
  commonConfig.logLevel  = config.LOG_DEBUG;
  commonConfig.preprocessors = {};
  commonConfig.preprocessors['./public/js/*.js'] = ['coverage'];

  config.set(commonConfig);
};
```

doing that allows me to run different karma configurations for different situations.

While developing I use:
    karma start config/karma.conf.js

To get my test coverage in all browsers I'd run: 
    karma start config/test.coverage.js

and to verify that my builds are clean as part of my continuous integration process I run 
    karma start config/build.conf.js

Using this method, I can again use grunt-exec to run those commands at the appropriate times.